# Doctrine Migration Error - "relation does not exist"

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, doctrine, database-migration

how do you create sql triggers with doctrine migrations?

here is migration:

```php
<?php
namespace App\Migrations;

use Doctrine\DBAL\Migrations\AbstractMigration;
use Doctrine\DBAL\Schema\Schema;
use Doctrine\DBAL\Schema\Table;

/**
 * Auto-generated Migration: Please modify to your needs!
 */
class Version20151211173441 extends AbstractMigration
{
    /**
     * @param Schema $schema
     */
    public function up(Schema $schema)
    {
        $table = $schema->createTable('public.users');
        $table->addColumn('id', 'integer', [
            'autoincrement' => true
        ]);
        $table->addColumn('name', 'string');
        $table->setPrimaryKey(['id']);

        $this->addSql("
            CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.users_insert_trigger()
                RETURNS TRIGGER AS $$
                BEGIN
                    NEW.name := NEW.name || ' test';
                    RETURN NEW;
                END;
                $$
                LANGUAGE plpgsql;
        ");

        $this->addSql("
            CREATE TRIGGER users_on_insert_trigger
                BEFORE INSERT ON public.users
                FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE public.users_insert_trigger();
        ");
    }

    /**
     * @param Schema $schema
     */
    public function down(Schema $schema)
    {
        $this->addSql("DROP TRIGGER public.users_on_insert_trigger ON users");
        $this->addSql("DROP FUNCTION public.users_insert_trigger()");
        $schema->dropTable('users');
    }
}
```

This produces the following error:

> SQLSTATE[42P01]: Undefined table: 7 ERROR:  relation "public.users"
>   does not exist

And produces the following sql:

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.users_insert_trigger()
    RETURNS TRIGGER AS $$
    BEGIN
        NEW.name := NEW.name || ' test';
        RETURN NEW;
    END;
    $$
    LANGUAGE plpgsql;

CREATE TRIGGER users_on_insert_trigger
    BEFORE INSERT ON public.users
    FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE public.users_insert_trigger();

CREATE TABLE public.users (id SERIAL NOT NULL, name VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL, PRIMARY KEY(id));
INSERT INTO common.migrations (version) VALUES ('20151211173441');
```

If I correctly understand, changes in schema is applied in the end of migration.
But it doesn't suit me...

So, how can i handle it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have correctly summarized the problem: the migration runner actually executes SQL you add via addSQL() before SQL generated using schemas.

You'll need to make this change as two separate migrations.

Answer (score 0):

ok, i found 2 related issues:

- https://github.com/doctrine/migrations/issues/352
- https://github.com/doctrine/migrations/issues/369

so you can:

1. as said @wschalle, you can handle it with two migration
2. another way - do not use Schema for migrations (i prefer)

without Schema you migration look like this

```php
<?php

public function up(Schema $schema)
{
    $platform = $this->connection->getSchemaManager()->getDatabasePlatform();

    $table = new Table('table_name'/*, ...*/);
    // ...

    $sql = $platform->getCreateTableSQL($table);
    // or
    $sql = $platform->getDropTableSQL($table);
    // etc.

    $this->addSql($sql);
}
```